# Show Animated GIF in GTK# Image Widget

Tags: c#, .net, mono, gtk, gtk#

I want to show an animated GIF in the GTK# Image widget to denote long running background operations. I tried opening the GIF and setting the Pixbuf, but the animation does not appear. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You need to set the [`PixbufAnimation` property](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=P%3AGtk.Image.PixbufAnimation) of the `Gtk.Image` to a `Gdk.PixbufAnimation` rather than setting the [`Pixbuf` property](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P%3AGtk.Image.Pixbuf).

For example:

```
// http://www.gifbin.com/987026
string gifPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "../../1351183938_high_school_football_player_kicks_67yard_goal.gif");
image1.PixbufAnimation = new Gdk.PixbufAnimation(gifPath);
```

I tested the above on an Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 'Trusty Tahr' machine with libgtk2.0-cil-dev 2.12.10-5 and saw the animation playing.

Comment: Thanks, will get back to you tomorrow.My xamarin studio just fails to build the project now saying > 
Build failed. Could not find type 'System.Globalization.SortVersion'.

Comment: Thanks a lot,it worked :).Is there a way to embed this GIF within the program,so that i dont need to distribute the GIF with the application as a file.

Comment: @techno:  In addition to the `Gdk.PixbufAnimation` constructor that takes a string (file path), there is [a constructor which takes a `Stream`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=C%3aGdk.PixbufAnimation.PixbufAnimation(System.IO.Stream)) and [a constructor which takes an `Assembly` and string (resource name)](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=C%3aGdk.PixbufAnimation.PixbufAnimation(System.Reflection.Assembly%2cstring)) to load from an embedded resource.